# Is there any foolproof way or method to ascertain that my sentence is perfectly grammatically correct?

Tags: writing

If you advise to consult an editor, how would I know that the editor is perfect in grammar? AI (artificial intelligence) apps cannot be as accurate as a human.
I don't understand why this question is off-topic and why it is closed and not accepting answers.

Comment: The venerable linguists Quirk and Svartvik explored the issue of divided opinions on the grammaticality of some example sentences. After well-controlled tests, they ended up saying that a Likert-like scale of grammaticality (I'm not sure if they took into account Gricean constraints) was more realistic than a dichotomous (yes or no) model. // The answer to your question is not 'It's impossible ever to say sentence 23 456 789 is totally grammatical' but 'this particular sentence may be (1) totally grammatical or (5) totally ungrammatical. Or somewhere in between.' It depends on the sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* maybe it got closed as proofreading because some folks thought that your original text is what you wanted to know whether was ok. I'm going to reöpen it, but you'll need to explain things that are not clear. See my next comment for some of these.

Comment: Professional editors are paid a decent salary to be good at what they do; otherwise they'll be quickly fired and on the street raking leaves. Why don't you trust them? Editors who are native speakers just "know" whether something is grammatical in a way that non-native speakers without decades of experience in the language simply can never approximate. Trust them. // As for computer programs, certainly there's no such thing as "AI" — that's just a marketing gimmick by some dumb company claiming its knowledge database is better than what goes on in your own head.  Ignore marketing claims.

Comment: Is this question specific to English? It seems to me to be about language in general.

Comment: It seems like a general philosophical question about epistemology: what is truth and certainty. Same would apply to any other subject where there are experts: how do you know what is true in history, science, etc. It's specifically phrased about doubting experts but there isn't anything unique to English language experts.

Comment: There are some things that AIs (or whatever you prefer to call them) are better than humans at (e.g. chess, certain classificatory problems), and others that they're worse at, so you'd need to prove they cannot be as accurate as a human at this. Or delete that claim.

Comment: Can you clarify your title and text? The title sounds like you want a way to check grammaticality of a given sentence, but your text sounds like you want to check the quality of an editor (or grammar checker). Which are you asking about? (edit to clarify)

Comment: Thank you all for so many answers, ideas, and suggestions. 
As Mr. Matt E. asked whether this question is specific to English. Yes, I am specifically talking about the English language. 
Mr. tchrist suggested trusting the professional proofreaders. We do trust them, but I think, only trusting them is not the best solution. Since humans can make mistakes, so maybe, we have to hire a second professional proofreader to countercheck the material for accuracy.
We get confused even with simple sentences. Take, for instance,       
An insect is in the tree.
An insect is on the tree.

Comment: If there were an objective, foolproof test, we could program that into an AI. But language is too complex and flexible for that, and even many native expert speakers will sometimes disagree.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, I think you're best chance is to go to someone with lots of credibility and experience. If you want to be very diligent, you can bring it to a few people. Of course, we're all humans and people we all make mistakes, but chances are that any mistakes a trained professional makes would go unnoticed by someone who isn't. There's also plenty of weird grammar in English where there are solid arguments for different grammatical structures, as in, there can be more than one right answer sometimes.

Comment: And change you’re to your.

Comment: Here, I'd say the 'right answer' would usually be available: (1) 'perfectly grammatical', or (5) 'totally ungrammatical' ... or (2,3,4) 'divided usage: 25%/50%/75% of these Doctors of English Language find it acceptable'.